# Rotating Shapes when arranging them into circle ppt vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I found a great script to arrange objects (shapes) into a circle here:
[Aligning Shapes in a Circle using VBA, Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-powerpoint/aligning-shapes-in-a-circle-using-vba/170632a9-427b-46c1-90ea-c0f7f8235863)

```
Sub Test()
Call AlignShapesInCircle(720 / 2, 540 / 2, 100, ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange)
End Sub
Function AlignShapesInCircle(x As Single, y As Single, r As Single, shprng As ShapeRange)
'x,y    = center point of the circle
'r      = radius of the circle
'shprng = the shape selection that needs to be arranged
Dim angle As Single
Dim currentangle As Single
Dim x1 As Single
Dim y1 As Single
Dim i As Integer
currentangle = 0
angle = 360 / shprng.count
For currentangle = 0 To 359 Step angle
    i = i + 1
    x1 = r * Cos(D2R(currentangle))
    y1 = r * Sin(D2R(currentangle))
    shprng(i).Left = x + x1
    shprng(i).Top = y + y1
Next
End Function
Function D2R(Degrees) As Double
    D2R = Degrees / 57.2957795130823
End Function

Function R2D(Radians) As Double
    R2D = 57.2957795130823 * Radians
End Function
```

Now I want the shapes to rotate so that if I use arrows the tip will always show towards the center.

I have to introduce a line here:

```
shprng(i).Left = x + x1
shprng(i).Top = y + y1
shprng(i).Rotation = ???
```

Any ideas where I could find the proper formula?

Answer (score 0):

Silly - figured it out - it was easier than I thought. Don't need any SIN and COS which frightened me - just:

shprng(i).Rotation = (360 / (shprng.Count)) * (i - 1)